# Pencil tool randomly changes color from foreground to background in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Out of nowhere my pencil tool has been randomly changing color to that of my bg color even when it's not selected. Pressure sensitivity isn't the case, or brush options, I've reset the brush preset, and even the CTRL-ALT-SHIFT open photoshop method. [image]

Here are an assortment of brush strokes, at random they turn into the background color. This only happens to my pencil tool, the brush tool works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Try turning **off** `Auto-erase` in the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen.

Auto-erase is a Pencil Tool option which tells the tool to use the *background color* if a new stroke is *started* on top of the *foreground color*.

Note that the very top tip of *all* the red strokes..... start on top of an area with the foreground color.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I just found out about the new stroke on top of the background color thing... so I knew there was some sort of consistency! I've been stressing about this for hours and I guess I accidentally toggled it on while drawing. Again thank you!